# JAVA Crear metodo que ya tiene valores asignados

Tags: java

No se como dar valor en el metodo a Obra de si esta asignada se debe lanzar una excepción. Está declarada obra como string.
Copio el enunciado, no logro el poder tener el objeto string Obra como único.

Para poder asignar una obra y posteriormente terminarla habrá que implementar los **métodos asignarObra y terminarObra**. El primero recibirá como parámetro el nombre de la obra y el segundo no recibirá ningún parámetro.

- Si el parámetro del método asignarObra es incorrecto, deberá lanzarse una excepción y se detendrá el proceso de instanciación del objeto. En este caso, las posibles excepciones que podrían lanzarse son:
- Si el método recibe un null en obra, la excepción será de tipo NullPointerException y el mensaje de error de la excepción debería ser del tipo "X".
  si el método recibe una cadena vacía en obra, la excepción será de tipo IllegalArgumenException y el mensaje de error de la excepción debería ser del tipo "X".
- Si se intenta asignar una obra pero ya había una obra asignada, se debería lanzar una excepción de tipo IllegalStateException con el mensaje "El teatro ya tiene una obra asignada".
- Del mismo modo, si se intenta terminar una obra sin que haya ninguna asignada, se lanzaría el mismo tipo de excepción IllegalStateException, aunque en este caso con el mensaje "El teatro no tiene una obra asignada que se pueda finalizar".

**La parte principal de mi código.**

```
// Atributos de objeto constantes (representan características inmutables)
private int codigoTeatro;                         // Codigo del teatro
private final String NombreTeatro;                         // Nombre del teatro    
private final int Aforo;                                // Aforo del teatro


// Atributos de objeto variable (representan el estado del vehiculo en un instante dado)
   
private String Obra;                                       // Obra que se está representando
private int EntradasVendidas;                           // Numero de entradas vendidas
```

**Y el código que llevo es el siguiente:**

```
public void asignarObra (String Obra) throws NullPointerException,IllegalStateException ,IllegalArgumentException {
    
    if (this.Obra == null){
        throw new NullPointerException ("El nombre de la obra no puede ser nulo");}
        
    if (this.Obra == ""){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("El nombre de la obra no puede ser cadena vacía");
    }    
    
    if (this.Obra != ""  ){
        throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro ya tiene una obra asignada");}

}
    
   
public void terminarObra() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    
if (this.Obra != null){
    throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada que se pueda finalizar");}

}
```

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: No se como dar valor en el metodo a Obra de si esta asignada se debe lanzar una excepción. Está declarada obra como string.

Comment: No sabemos donde guardas las obras... pero basicamente tenes que hacer esa comparacion..

Comment: // Atributos de objeto variable (representan el estado del vehiculo en un instante dado)
       
    private String Obra;                                       // Obra que se está representando
    private int EntradasVendidas;                           // Numero de entradas vendidas

Comment: El código va EN la pregunta, yendo a [edit]. En los comentarios es infumable y no se ve si tiene algún error. La mejor forma de _contar_ lo que cuentas en el inicio de la pregunta es mostrando el código. En la pregunta.

Comment: Disculpe, soy nuevo. Lo hago ahora mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private int codigoTeatro;                         
private final String NombreTeatro;         
private final int Aforo;                              

private String Obra; 
private int EntradasVendidas;


public void asignarObra( String Obra ) throws NullPointerException,IllegalStateException ,IllegalArgumentException { 
  if ( Obra == null ) {
      throw new NullPointerException( "El nombre de la obra no puede ser nulo" );
  }
  if ( Obra.equals( "" )) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "El nombre de la obra no puede ser cadena vacía" );
  } 
  if ( ! this.Obra.equals( "" )){
      throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro ya tiene una obra asignada"); 
  }
```

}

```
public void terminarObra() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if ( this.Obra == null ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada que se pueda finalizar");
    }
}
```

Lo llevabas bien encaminado, pero te equivocaste con los this, yo personalmente, prefiero modificar los nombres para no usarlos, por ejemplo:

```
void setNombre( String elNombre ) {
    nombre = elNombre;
}
```

Esto me evita las posibles confuciones... y escribo menos.
Dentro de asignaObra, primero haces las verificaciones de Obra, osea el dato que se pasa como parámetro de la función, y lanzas de ser necesario, la excepción correspondiente.
Luego haces lo correspondiente con this.Obra, osea que el objeto Obra que tienes, este o no en null, y obras en consecuencia.
Luego en terminarObra, verificas que this.Obra no sea null.

Comment: Me sigue sin funcionar quitando los dos primeros this

Comment: Perdon @antonio, cometí el error de copiar tu código sin pensar, estabamos comparando cadenas con ==, y se deben comparar con equals, edite mi respuesta, lo he probado y funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Solucionado